# Nginx regex with a dash

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-config

I am using this solution to match multiple backend urls in NGINX:

```
location ~ ^/(api|admin|jet) {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
}
```

I want to match a fourth url which contains a dash like so (not working):

```
location ~ ^/(api|admin|simple-admin|jet) {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
}
```

How could I do that ? I've also tried to escape the dash with double quotes.

Comment: Just tested this regex with nginx and it is working as expected. Maybe some other location block captures `/simple-admin` location before this one?

Comment: Also, make sure that you inserted a hyphen and not something that looks like a hyphen (e.g. en dash).